# How to configure Crap4J

Tags: xml, ant, jenkins

I'm trying to configure Crap4J for Jenkins but there is absolute no examples or how tos for this plugin.

I've found the following [documentation](http://www.crap4j.org/ant_usage.html) and the [build.xml](https://code.google.com/p/crap4j/source/browse/trunk/org.crap4j/doc/example_build.xml)
but I need it in a seperate `crap4j.xml` file because I receive this error from Ant:

```
BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test/build.xml:128: taskdef class org.crap4j.anttask.Crap4jAntTask cannot be found
using the classloader AntClassLoader[/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/crap4j/lib/crap4j_ant_latest.jar]
```

UPDATE:

```
127: <property name="CRAP4J_HOME" value="/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/crap4j" />
128: <taskdef name="crap4j" classname="org.crap4j.anttask.Crap4jAntTask">
129:    <classpath>
130:        <fileset dir="${CRAP4J_HOME}/lib">
131:            <include name="**/*.jar" />
132:        </fileset>
133:    </classpath>
134: </taskdef>
```

Comment: pls share the exact code that **you're** using, as well as the **line number: 128** in `build.xml`, where it's failing

Comment: @sunbabaphu I've added the related code from my build.xml

Comment: could you manually check here: `/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/crap4j`, if there's a `/lib/org.crap4j.jar` present, and then just see if within this jar, there is `org/crap4j/anttask/Crap4jAntTask.class` present. mainly, your error relates to a bug on **windows**. but, since you're not on windows, it must be something else

Comment: It's not present. I've downloaded the jar from http://www.crap4j.org/downloads/crap4j_ant_latest.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- download the `crap4j_ant_latest.jar`
- extract the contents of the *jar* to any folder, say `/var/lib/jenkins/plugins`. This will create a folder `crap4j` under the above directory.
- browse to `/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/crap4j/lib/org.crap4j.jar`, and see if you have the following `Crap4jAntTask.class` file, inside `org.crap4j.jar`, at `org/crap4j/anttask/Crap4jAntTask.class`.

if the above holds true, then [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24824572/2857402) error should be resolved too.

Answer (score 0):

That's an Ant issue, make sure when you configure your build.xml that you get all the directories set up consistently. That error looks like you have identified a file somewhere that should be a directory.

Its been years since I used Crap4J. I liked it, but it seemed to become an abandoned project. If you're interested in code analysis, you might look at [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/). It collects the data needed for the CRAP metric, and a lot more besides.  I have a view in my installation that creates a treemap by coverage and complexity, giving me a very nice visual CRAP report.